# Google spreadsheet - Case sensitive COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm using countifs to find all rows that match certain criteria's, but it doesn't work. Some example rows:

```
abc     abc    6542543
abc     Abc    
def     Def    43243
def     def    12344322
```

I need to count all rows where the first column is the same, the last column is NOT the same and the third column is NOT empty. In this example, that would yield 1 for all rows except the first.

These are my formulas and expected outcomes:

```
=countifs(A$1:A,A1,B$1:B,"<>"&B1,C$1:C,"<>")    0
=countifs(A$1:A,A2,B$1:B,"<>"&B2,C$1:C,"<>")    1
=countifs(A$1:A,A3,B$1:B,"<>"&B3,C$1:C,"<>")    1
=countifs(A$1:A,A4,B$1:B,"<>"&B4,C$1:C,"<>")    1
```

However, it yields 0 everywhere. This is because countifs works case insensitively. How do I solve this to be case sensitive?

Comment: I just realised the problem occurs because it works case sensitively... I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: What would be the expected outcome?

Comment: Exactly. I've added the expected outcome to the formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and EXACT.  Put this in C1 and copy down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((EXACT($A$1:$A$4,A1))*(NOT(EXACT($B$1:$B$4,B1)))*($C$1:$C$4<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much